# How to set start and stop input in Python which generating word list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try Hard to figure out how to Input start and stop word for my Python wordlist generator.

Here is my code:

```
import itertools

   wrds = 'abcd0123'
   n = 5

   for i in itertools.product(wrds, repeat = n):
      a = ''.join(i)
      print(a)
```

My generator is giving me output like this as usual: `aaaaa`, `aaaab`, `aaaac`,...

But how set the inputs in order to take a starting point and an ending point?.

My length is 5. I want to generate for example from aaac1 to aaad3.
How can I achieve this? I'm completely stuck.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input For *interactivily* provide user input to your program. So, this means, whenever this function is encountered, the program stops, and you need (as a user) to type stuff (in a command line) for the program to proceed. This typed stuff will now be outputted by the `output()` function in your program.

Comment: I know the input function But how to implement in this code so it starts with aaad3 to aaad3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very common and beginner of doing is

```
import itertools

start_string=input("Enter start string: ")
end_string=input("Enter ending string: ")

wrds = 'abcd0123'
n = 5
empty_list=[]

for i in itertools.product(wrds, repeat = n):
    empty_list.append(''.join(i))

if start_string in empty_list:
    start_=empty_list.index(start_string)


if end_string in empty_list:
    end_=empty_list.index(end_string)

print(empty_list[start_:end_+1])
```

To have output line by line replace last print statement with below code

```
for item in empty_list[start_:end_+1]:
    print(item)
```

If you want to pass start string & ending string in random index order and if you want let code itself decide the index then you can use below code

```
import itertools

string_1=input("Enter start string: ")
string_2=input("Enter ending string: ")

wrds = 'abcd0123'
n = 5
empty_list=[]

for i in itertools.product(wrds, repeat = n):
    empty_list.append(''.join(i))

if string_1 in empty_list:
    index_1=empty_list.index(string_1)

if string_2 in empty_list:
    index_2=empty_list.index(string_2)

if index_1 > index_2 :
    start_ = index_2
    end_ = index_1 + 1
else :
    start_ = index_1
    end_ = index_2+1

for item in empty_list[start_:end_]:
    print(item)
```

To get count, you can use len() function

```
print("Length: ", len(empty_list[start_:end_]))
```

And if you are trying to find out good head start with Python basics I suggest you to read https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html. Its very small and can read in a single day.

Comment: But it is not coming line by line? Like :- aaac1 in first line aaac2 in second line .. and so on?

Comment: @PradhanBanra what function you are referring to ?

Comment: They are not functions, they are variables used for storing your strings but input read via input() function. if you want to know more about input() function you can refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: How to add a count function to it and print it at the last? means count of how many lines of that.

Comment: How to do this program in GPU so that i can increase the speed of it . write a full program code to let me understand.

Comment: @PradhanBanra, No. You have to figure it out your self or raise a different question. And do your homework buddy.